# Get next date after an arbitrary date in a Python Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, series

I have a DataFrame in Python that has a "date" column (and several other columns).

What I want to do is to split off two DFs based on an arbitrary date in the "date" column. Let this split point be `arbitrary_date`.

1. All rows with a date **before** `arbitrary_date`
2. Any rows with the one next date in the series (which may be `arbitrary_date` or another date up to a week in the future)

To be clear -

- I don't know what the arbitrary date will be until runtime
- I cannot split by index because I have no guarantee than any specific indices go into either DF
- I don't know how many days will elapse between the arbitrary date and the next date
- I don't know how many of the next date (after `arbitrary_date`) will be in the DF

Here's an example to give a bit of realism to the request.

Start with this DF.

```
date        data
20230101    e
20230108    E
20230115    S
20230117    L
20230117    f
20230118    u
20230118    B
20230121    r
20230127    n
20230128    o
```

If my arbitrary date is 2023-01-17 then I want the two DFs to be

```
20230101    e
20230108    E
20230115    S
```

and

```
20230117    L
20230117    f
```

But if my arbitrary date is 2023-01-22 then my DFs should be

```
20230101    e
20230108    E
20230115    S
20230117    L
20230117    f
20230118    u
20230118    B
20230121    r
```

and

```
20230127    n
```

How can I accomplish this dynamic split?

Comment: What did you try? Could you add some examples of some code not working as you wish? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: I thought through possible ways to do it, yet everything I thought of had issues. I wasn't even sure how to start, and hence the question. I can't just say "> date" because that captures everything after the date and I don't want everything after the date. I can't say "< date + 7" (or some such) because there could be other dates within a week that I don't want to capture. I can't say "next 2 rows" because there might be 1 or 2 or 3 or more rows that I want to capture. I can't say "= next_date" because I don't know what "next date" actually is before runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
def split_df(df, date):
    split_date = pd.to_datetime(date)

    next_date = df["date"].between(split_date, split_date + pd.Timedelta(days=7))

    df1 = df[df["date"] < split_date]
    try:
        df2 = df[df["date"].eq(df.loc[next_date, "date"].iat[0])]
    except IndexError:
        df2 = None

    return df1, df2


df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y%M%d")

print(*split_df(df, "2023-01-17"), sep="\n\n")
print()

print(*split_df(df, "2023-01-22"), sep="\n\n")
print()

print(*split_df(df, "2023-02-22"), sep="\n\n")
```

Prints:

```
                 date data
0 2023-01-01 00:01:00    e
1 2023-01-08 00:01:00    E
2 2023-01-15 00:01:00    S

                 date data
3 2023-01-17 00:01:00    L
4 2023-01-17 00:01:00    f


                 date data
0 2023-01-01 00:01:00    e
1 2023-01-08 00:01:00    E
2 2023-01-15 00:01:00    S
3 2023-01-17 00:01:00    L
4 2023-01-17 00:01:00    f
5 2023-01-18 00:01:00    u
6 2023-01-18 00:01:00    B
7 2023-01-21 00:01:00    r

                 date data
8 2023-01-27 00:01:00    n


                 date data
0 2023-01-01 00:01:00    e
1 2023-01-08 00:01:00    E
2 2023-01-15 00:01:00    S
3 2023-01-17 00:01:00    L
4 2023-01-17 00:01:00    f
5 2023-01-18 00:01:00    u
6 2023-01-18 00:01:00    B
7 2023-01-21 00:01:00    r
8 2023-01-27 00:01:00    n
9 2023-01-28 00:01:00    o

None
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Andrej Kesely's answer as inspiration to go with a slightly different approach. I know that the "next date" is going to be some time within the coming week. Hence I can use the ".between" method to get all the dates that occur on the day of and within the 6 days after that day. Then I can take the min of those dates to get the date I want and then filter the original DF on that value.

```
next_day = df[df['Date'].between(arbitrary_date, arbitrary_date+ pd.Timedelta(days=7))]['Date'].min()
search_data = df.loc[df['Date'] == next_day]

Thank you, Andrej
```